# Laravel 4.2 & Jquery Uniform Cannot Post Checkboxes

Tags: jquery, laravel, uniform

When i try to post my form i cant getting checkboxes. All other form elements are coming with post but checkboxes dont coming.

I try remove jquery.uniform from my html page and try again later all form elements and checkboxes successfully coming with post. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using laravel html elements?
I think Laravel has a function which allows the user to add form in the HTML pages.

Maybe you can try Form::checkbox('name', 'value');

Here is the link of Laravel form elements:http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#form-model-binding

Comment: I try laravel form elements too. doesnt matter problem with jquery uniform when i remove uniform.min.js from layout. all data and checkboxes data successfully posted. but when i add uniform.min.js to layout all data posted without checkboxed data. if you have laravel 4.2 on your localhost try it you can see too.